# Why i am getting java.lang.NullPointerException even after initializing the local variable

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

Apr 06, 2018 3:15:29 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet dispatcher threw exception **java.lang.NullPointerException**

**Here is my code:**

I am getting nullPointerException at second yellow line.
[image]

Comment: where is the initialization for `encryptPassword`?

Comment: Couple of notes here, you'll get a better response if you paste the code in (don't screenshot) and if you include the full stack trace.

Comment: Actually i made an object encryptPassword (globally) for EncryptPassword class which has method decrypt() in it.

Comment: @PrecisoSensedge It seems you don't understand the nature of NPE. The left-hand side can't cause this exception. Please, read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it

Comment: @PrecisoSensedge, the variable can be not initialised and everything is going to be OK if neither `encryptPassword` nor `dbEncryptedPassword` is `null`

Comment: Please don't paste screenshots when it is possible to paste text

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you have not initialised the `encryptPassword` variable so it is `null` by default, causing `encryptPassword.decrypt` to throw an exception.

Another possible cause is that `properties.getProperty("database.password")` is returning `null`, which you're then passing into `encryptPassword.decrypt` which expects a non-`null` argument.